# Inserting JSON as string to mysql fails in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update some data to mysql in python using the Insert query. If I pass in the string, it is working fine and updating the data in the database. However when I try to add a JSON as string to the query, it gives me the syntax error. Here is what I am doing and the output.

```
check = process_quote(json_data)
 # check returns a json.dumps(jsonVal) as a string
update_job_status(job_id, consts.COMPLETED_STATUS, check)


# update mysql table
def update_job_status(job_id, target_status, result):
    c_mysql = create_mysql()
    mysql_dict = {"request_result": target_status, "request_ID": job_id, "result": result}
    c_mysql.insert_row(consts.MYSQL_TABLE, mysql_dict)

def insert_row(self, table_name, row_obj):

        keys = row_obj.keys()
        print("the Keys are : ")
        print(keys)
        values = map(lambda v: self.sql_quote_col(row_obj[v]), keys)
        update_values = map(lambda v: "%s=VALUES(%s)" % (v, v), keys)
        print(list(update_values))
        sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO {database_name}.{table_name} ({column_names}) VALUES ({column_values});""".format(database_name=consts.databaseNAME,table_name=table_name,column_names=", ".join(keys),column_values=", ".join(values))
        # logging.debug(sql)
        print(sql)
        self.write_query(sql)



def sql_quote_col(self, val):
        if type(val) is str:
            return "\"%s\"" % val
        elif val is None:
            return "NULL"
        else:
            return "%s" % str(val)

def write_query(self, sql):
        logging.info(sql)
        self.writeDb = self.connect()
        cursor = self.writeDb.cursor()
        # try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # except:
        #     logging.error("sql query execution fails: %s" % sql)
        cursor.close()
        self.writeDb.commit()
        self.writeDb.close()
```

When I tried to identify the query by printing the statement, I found the issue that the json element has been having double "" . The query looks like :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO databasename.tablename (request_result, request_ID, result) VALUES ("completed", "id_val", ""{\"First Name\":\"value\",\"Middle Initial\":\"E\",\"Last Name\":\"Testing\",\"value\":\"somevalue\"}"");
```

I can understand that the problem lies because of double quotation but I am not able to identify why there are 2 quotes adding to the same. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't have enough information to provide a good answer - the solution is not to paste the values into the query, but instead put `?` where a value would go and then pass the replacements to the actual method running the query - but you didn't share that code (i.e. `.write_query`) nor did you share the code that defines the values, like `column_names` for example. This both solves your problem and helps prevent SQL injection issues.

Comment: @Grismar I have shared the `write_query` function. The SQL query is present in `insert_row`. The definition of column is done by using dictionary in `update_job_status`. I have pasted all the functions being used to achieve the same. I don't understand what functions are you talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is open to SQL injection, and solving that also solves your formatting issues.

If you have multiple calls to `write_query`, you may want to reuse the connection instead of creating a new one every time it is called. However, just using what you have, this is how to change `write_query`:

Changes:

```
def write_query(self, sql, values):
    self.writeDb = self.connect()
    cursor = self.writeDb.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(*values))
    self.writeDb.commit()
    self.writeDb.close()
```

And where you're calling it:

```
        sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO {database_name}.{table_name} ({column_names}) VALUES ({column_values});""".format(database_name=consts.databaseNAME, table_name=table_name, column_names=", ".join(keys), column_values=", ".join(['?' for __ in keys]))
        self.write_query(sql, values)
```

Note that I can't really test what I wrote here, since you didn't provide a minimal, reproducible example, but I think it should be clear what the idea is here.

In general, instead of doing this:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = "value"'
conn.execute(sql)
```

You should do this:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?'
conn.execute(sql, (value,))
```